# I have a problem with dependencies of a task

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am attesting the screenshot which is giving error and cant build my app from flutter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqhuB.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

The problem is described clearly in the error message, you have not accepted the Android SDK License which is required to be accepted before actually use the SDK.

If you run `flutter doctor` you will see an error message similar to this one in the red box with a command to fix it:

[image]

---

### Solution:

All you have to do is to just run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in the terminal or command prompt and pressing `y` to accept every part in the license.